# Does snakebite handle retry in case of cluster failure?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, snakebite

snakebite recently come as an alternative to hdfs cli. According to my understanding hdfs does not do retry of command, if command failed due to cluster issue. 
My question here is that does `snakebite` handle the retry in case of cluster failure. By retry I mean it tries the command several time if the command is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes from the cli interface it does opt for retry. But after a time when enough retry fails, It does fail.